# Why is my code not showing any output? I am trying to use while loop to debug the error i was getting before it

Tags: python

```
f = file.readlines()
l = 0
while l <= len(f):
    for i in range(l):
        x = f[i]
        l += 1
        for a in x:
            if a == "a":
                f.pop(i)
                break
            else:
                continue
print(f)
file.close()
```

I want to pop any line from the data which has any character 'a' in it.

Comment: Why use a while loop instead of a for loop?

Comment: because I can't use it....the list's length keep decreasing.

Comment: Have a look at the first two lines `while l <= len(f):
    for i in range(l):` Notice that l = 0, so your first for loop will actually never run and you will be stuck in the while loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to manage your own line counter and iterate over each line
character by character. The file itself is iterable without using `readlines`, and the `in` operator tells you at once if `"a"` is a character in a given line.

```
with open("filename") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "a" in line:
            print(line, end="")  # line already ends with a newline
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so quick!

Answer (score 4):

Im not quite understanding the way your code is supposed to work, but this would solve your problem too:

```
f = file.readlines()

for line in reversed(f):
    if "a" in line:
        f.remove(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

`for i in range(l)` when l is zero will cause the loop to run zero times.

Comment: But since `l` is one afterwards it would print something in the next iteration of the while loop.

Comment: No it won't. It will never get to the increment portion.